# Sample from different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I have a vector of probabilities, let's say

```
prob=c(0.1,0.8,0.1)
```

and a dataframe : `df=cbind(c("A","B","A"),c(1,2,3),c("q","v","z"))`

and i want to sample `n` object from df with replacement, with 0.1 probability from first column, 0.8 from second and 0.1 from the the third

Comment: are you sampling n columns or n elements from the columns? does one sample include the whole column or does one sample include just one element eg "A"??

Comment: i want to sample n total elements, 10% has to be from first column, 80% from second and 10% from the last one

Comment: Psst... I think you want to replace that `cbind()` with `data.frame()` - you get a `matrix` at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll unlist the data.frame, and modify our `prob` vector on the fly so it has the appropriate length.

```
df <- data.frame(c("A","B","A"), c(1,2,3), c("q","v","z"), stringsAsFactors = F)

n <- 5
set.seed(1)
unname(sample(unlist(df), n, replace = TRUE, prob= rep(prob, each = nrow(df))))
# [1] "3" "1" "A" "z" "2"
```

---

If you really start from a matrix and not a `data.frame` that's a bit shorter:

```
df=cbind(c("A","B","A"),c(1,2,3),c("q","v","z"))
set.seed(1)
sample(df, n, replace = TRUE, prob= rep(prob, each = nrow(df)))
# [1] "3" "1" "A" "z" "2"
```

---

From a list (answering comments)

```
l =list(c("A","B"),c(1,2,3),c("q","v","z","w"))
set.seed(1)
sample(unlist(l), n, replace = TRUE, prob= rep(prob/lengths(l), lengths(l)))
# [1] "3" "2" "1" "v" "3" "B" "q"
```

Comment: if it were instead of a dataframe a list, where each column differs in length?

Comment: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the assumption that the sample probabilities *within one column* are uniform:

We first sample `n` column positions using the probabilities in vector `prob`;

```
df=cbind(c("A","B","A"),c(1,2,3),c("q","v","z"))
prob=c(0.1,0.8,0.1)
n = 10

set.seed(1)
colselect <- sample(1:ncol(df), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = prob)

[1] 2 2 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 2
```

Then we loop over the column positions and sample one element from the respective column each:

```
sapply(colselect, function(x) sample(df[,x], 1))

[1] "1" "1" "3" "B" "3" "v" "A" "3" "2" "3"
```

Comment: I did not said that the probabilities are uniform within each column, i asked this question because i want to sample from each column with a specific probability

Comment: Yes, but the probabilities of which value to sample from one specific column is uniform, or is it not? You sample a specific column with a specific probability, but you don't care which value to sample from this column.

Comment: This is the exact solution I came to. Use the probabilities to decide how many elements you're going to sample from each column, and then sample from each column. The with replacement within the column is solved by taking one item at a time with no constraint. @gldzzzz - unless you add more detail - perhaps by giving us an example - then it is completely unclear why this doesn't solve your problem.